# Introducing a express middleware in NodeJS TypeScript OOP

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to introducing cls-rtracer and when instantiating it, it's coming as undefined.

The code is written in TypeScript using Object Oriented Paradigm instead of Functional.

Examples posted in NPM for the library are functional.

I've commented the place where it is coming as undefined.

Introducing any other middleware in this express app seems straightforward except cls-rtracer

This is the code:

```
import express, {NextFunction, Response, Request} from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import swaggerui from 'swagger-ui-express';
import {Controller} from './api/v1/controllers/Controller';
import {logger} from './api/v1/utils/Logger';
import {errorHandler} from './api/v1/utils/ErrorHandler';
import {BaseError} from './api/v1/utils/BaseError';
import {HttpStatusCode} from './api/v1/constants/HttpStatusCode';
import rTracer from 'cls-rtracer';

export const stream = {
  write: (text: string) => {
    logger.info(text.replace(/\n$/, ''));
  },
};

const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'Backend',
      descriptions: 'Service',
      contact: {
        name: '',
      },
      servers: ['http://localhost:8080//api/v1/domain'],
      version: '1.0.1',
    },
  },
  apis: ['./api/v1/routes/*.ts'],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);

export class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  public port: number;

  constructor(controllers: Controller[], port: number) {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = port;
    this.initializeMiddlewares();
    this.initializeHealth();
    this.initializeControllers(controllers);
    this.initializeErrorHandler();
    this.initializeSwagger();
  }

  private initializeMiddlewares() {
    this.app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
    const requestId = rTracer.id();
    console.log(requestId); // giving undefined
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(
        morgan(
            [
              'ip: :remote-addr',
              ':method', ':url', 'HTTP/:http-version', 'status: :status',
              ':res[content-length]', 'referrer: :referrer',
              'userAgent: :user-agent', 'responseTime: :response-time ms',
            ].join(' | '),
            {stream: stream},
        ),
    );
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(helmet());
  }

  private initializeControllers(controllers: Controller[]) {
    controllers.forEach((controller) => {
      this.app.use('/', controller.router);
    });
  }

  private initializeErrorHandler() {
    this.app.use(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const error = new BaseError('Not Found', HttpStatusCode.NOT_FOUND, true, 'Not Found');
      next(error);
    });
    this.app.use(async (error: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      if (!errorHandler.isTrustedError(error)) {
        // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
        res.status(error.status).json(error);
      }
      await errorHandler.handleError(error);
      // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
      res.status(error.httpCode || HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER).json({error: error});
    });
  }

  private initializeSwagger() {
    this.app.use(
        '/api-docs',
        swaggerui.serve,
        swaggerui.setup(swaggerDocs, {explorer: true}),
    );
  }

  private initializeHealth() { }

  public listen() {
    this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
      logger.info(`listening on the port ${this.port}`);
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why does it work flawlessly in the code below:

```
import express from 'express';
import {CONFIG} from './config';
import MasterRouter from './routers/MasterRouter';
import ErrorHandler from './utils/ErrorHandler';
import rTracer from 'cls-rtracer';
import morgan from 'morgan';

class Server {
  public app = express();
  public router = MasterRouter;

  constructor(
  ) {
    this.correlationalIdMiddleware();
    this.loggingMiddleware();
    this.routingMiddleware();
    this.errorHandlingMiddleWare();
  }

  correlationalIdMiddleware() {
    this.app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
  }

  loggingMiddleware() {
    this.app.use(morgan((tokens, req, res) => {
      const requestId = rTracer.id();
      return [
        `> requestId: ${requestId} -`,
        tokens.method(req, res),
        tokens.url(req, res),
        tokens.status(req, res),
        tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
        tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms',
      ].join(' ');
    }));
  }

  routingMiddleware() {
    this.app.use('/api', this.router);
  }

  errorHandlingMiddleWare() {
    this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
      const error = new ErrorHandler(404, 'Not Found');
      next(error);
    });
    this.app.use((error: ErrorHandler, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
      const errorObject = {
        status: 'error',
        statusCode: error.statusCode,
        message: error.message,
      };
      const requestId = rTracer.id();
      console.log(`> requestId: ${requestId} - ${JSON.stringify(errorObject)}`);
      res.status(error.statusCode || 500).json(errorObject);
    });
  }
}

const server = new Server;

server.app.listen(CONFIG.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`> Server listening on ${CONFIG.PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: You are supposed to use `rTracer.id()` in a route handler like so `this.app.get('/', function(){ console.log(rTracer.id()) })` You call it in a place where no request exists.

Comment: @Molda i've modified the question. in the code i've added, why does it work flawlessly? is this a problem in the router/controller?

Comment: It works because you call `rTracer.id()` within a middleware/route handler. The `rTracer.id()` function gets the id from request So if you call the function outside any middleware/route handler then rTracer has no request to get the id from.